# getActivity() inside Fragment sometimes crash

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I need the context inside my fragment, I use getActivity(), but sometimes this code crash  give me NullPointer, I believe because android continue execute code in fragment but activity already died.

So, to fix it, I need always use:

```
final Activity activity = getActivity();
if(activity != null) {
   //TODO: Use activity here
}
```

But it's sux always verifiy if Activity is not null,
Have some other way to do it without crash?

Comment: The activity that is hosting the Fragment never dies, a Fragment cannot be displayed without a host Activity. Do you try to do something in the Fragment before you add it to an Activity, or after you remove it from an Activity?

Comment: No, but I use AsyncTasks in Fragment (executing in onCreateView), in OnPostExecute of my AsyncTask I use getActivity, in this situation give me NullPointer, I believe that because a new activity take on foreground, and Android execute onPostExecute of AsyncTask from my first activity, but already lost de reference.

Comment: Oh, so you have a headless Fragment that isn't a part of the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably right. When your AsyncTask comes to `onPostExecute` the Activity might have ended.

You need to `cancel()` the AsyncTask when the Fragment detaches from the Activity. This will ensure, that `onPostExecute` will not be called.

Comment: Thanks! I has not thought in it.